# Stokes' Theorem on a punctured surface

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, calculus

Say we consider a punctured surface. For instance, $D^2 \setminus \{0\}$. We consider a vector field on this surface that is divergent at $0$. It could be proportional to $v(r) \sim\frac{1}{|r|^n}$. Is there a way to still apply Stokes' Theorem here when we want to calculate the flux of the curl of this vector field through the surface? I have been looking for an additional contribution coming from the pole but without any luck. Any help would be much appreciated! As would any literature on the subject.

Comment: I agree that the MathSE would be a better home for this question.  That being said, Stokes' theorem relates the flux of $\nabla \times \vec v$ through an open surface to the line integral of $\vec v$ around the boundary, or (in the guise of the divergence theorem) the flux of $\vec v$ through a *closed* surface to the integral of $\nabla \cdot \vec v$ over the interior volume.  Your question doesn't seem to refer to either case. How would you anticipate using Stokes' theorem in the simpler case of a smooth vector field?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean the first case, where we consider the flux of $\nabla \times v$ through the surface.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it correct.Also, isn't the use of “pole” misleading?

Comment: @TedShifrin I changed the question. Any chance you could help me in the right direction?

Comment: Stokes' theorem would apply to the region with the singularity excluded. In your example this would result in two line integrals, one being round the singularity. You'd have to make sense of that, possibly, in a principal value sense.

Comment: @Aruralreader I have thought about this but it seemed arbitrary to me. What should be the radius of this second line integral? I feel like my answer will depend on this.

Comment: Pick a small radius, say $\epsilon > 0$, and see if you can bound the integral as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0+$.

Comment: For the [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) induced by $v$ the divergence theorem applies.

Comment: Stokes' theorem applies for integrals of compactly supported forms over manifolds with boundary, so you would neet to consider the integral of your form over anuli of inner radii $\epsilon$ as $\epsilon\to0$, as A rural reader suggested.